# How can I fix the i/o timeout error when install Go dependencies using VSCode WSL?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am facing this error for every Go dependency I've been trying to install on VSCode WSL

```
Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest FAILED
{
 "code": 1,
 "killed": false,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go-1.20.4/bin/go install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest: module golang.org/x/tools/gopls: Get \"https://proxy.golang.org/golang.org/x/tools/gopls/@v/list\": dial tcp 142.251.42.241:443: i/o timeout\n"
}

1 tools failed to install.

gopls: failed to install gopls(golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest): Error: Command failed: /usr/local/go-1.20.4/bin/go install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
go: golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest: module golang.org/x/tools/gopls: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/golang.org/x/tools/gopls/@v/list": dial tcp 142.251.42.241:443: i/o timeout
```

Previously I have also encountered problems like i/o timeout during installing frameworks written in golang. It is due to the fact that I am located in mainland China. The problem is fixed when I start to use the proxy `golang.cn`.

But this time this does not seem to work. I run vscode as administrator but it also doesn't fix the problem.

I am wondering how I could fix this?

Comment: Does running `go env -w GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn,direct` in the WSL CLI work?